# Attributing Itemid to article when opened from a "Tagged Items" pages

Tags: php, menu-item, jroute, navigation

I am struggling with the tag component. 
1) When I click on the title of an article from the `component/tags/tag/MyTag` page, then I am redirected to a page with the home itemid. This is a big issues because there is many modules displaying that I don't want on a article.

I would like to either keep the same itemid as the `component/tags/tag/` page for this new page or to have a static itemid (Article link navigation overwrite) for example the `itemid=200`

I found in `com_tags\tag\default_items.php` the line that give this redirection but couldn't manage to find the solution.

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->content_item_id, $item->core_alias, $item->core_catid, $item->core_language, $item->type_alias, $item->router)); ?>">
   <?php echo $this->escape($item->core_title); ?>
</a>
```

You can see what I mean [here](http://www.rscmovement.org/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id=2-science-fr&lang=fr)

2) The title of my article aren't displayed at all.

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit :

- If I add `&Itemid=200` at the end it working if I am not in SEF url even if there is 2 itemid in the URL. But in SEF url, it'snt working.
- If I assign the article to language ALL then it's also working: the itemid is preserved and the title is displayed: but this is not a long-term solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a new menu called HIDDEN (i.e wont actually be displayed on the site
- Create a menu item in there to display all the category parents in either list or blog layout. Doesn't matter, just so long as the articles 'tagged' are in a category covered by a menu item.

If you just have ONE root category for all items, the one item should be sufficient. Make sure all articles belong to a category in this menu (either directly or as a child)

You should now find that when you click an item from the TAG list, it will use the menu itemid of the menu item that contains the category.

Basically, if joomla cannot find a menu item that references the article in someway either directly or via the category, it will just use the index page by default.

Hope this makes sense, and SHOULD solve your problem. This doesn't crop up often as people invariably have somewhere on their site a menu item of blog / display category type.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried with the menu item "tagged items" but it didn't work. You're right I don't have a category menu item, most of my menus are single article in which I display the category with the module DisplayNews (I find it more flexible). I can't believe you solved that! That's really great!